# pivot to avoid numerous joins in TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have the following table :

```
student teacher grade   gradedate
--------------------------------------
1       ALICE   A       05.08.2016
1       BOB     A       25.01.2015
1       CHARLES C       12.05.2017
1       DAVID   B       25.09.2013
2       BOB     D       01.02.2014
2       CHARLES A       26.04.2016
2       DAVID   C       02.05.2016
```

(student,teacher) is the primary key of this table.

And I want to generate a result like this

```
student ALICEGrade  ALICEGradeDate  BOBGrade    BOBGradeDate    CHARLESGrade    CHARLESGradeDate    DAVIDGrade  DAVIDGradeDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       A           05.08.2016      A           25.01.2015      C               12.05.2017          B           25.09.2013
2       NULL        NULL            D           01.02.2014      A               26.04.2016          C           02.05.2016
```

I managed to produce it by using join clause for each teacher:

```
SELECT st.student, 
a.grade as [ALICEGrade], a.gradedate as [ALICEGradeDate], 
b.grade as [BOBGrade], b.gradedate as [BOBGradeDate],
c.grade as [CHARLESGrade], c.gradedate as [CHARLESGradeDate],
d.grade as [DAVIDGrade], d.gradedate as [DAVIDGradeDate] 
FROM
(SELECT distinct [student] FROM [dbo].[TESTGRADETABLE]) st
LEFT join [dbo].[TESTGRADETABLE] a on a.teacher = 'ALICE' and a.student = st.student 
LEFT join [dbo].[TESTGRADETABLE] b on b.teacher = 'BOB' and b.student = st.student 
LEFT join [dbo].[TESTGRADETABLE] c on c.teacher = 'CHARLES' and c.student = st.student
LEFT join [dbo].[TESTGRADETABLE] d on d.teacher = 'DAVID' and d.student = st.student
```

But I was wondering if there is another more elegant solution to avoid the numerous joins ( the real request has around 10 joins). I was thinking to use pivot starting from:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TESTGRADETABLE] 
pivot
(
    max(grade)
    for  teacher in ([ALICE],[BOB],[CHARLES],[DAVE])
) piv1
```

but I am stuck here. I do not know if it possible to generate TeacherGradeDate columns with it.

The TSQL to create table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTGRADETABLE](
    [student] [int] NOT NULL,
    [teacher] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [grade] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [gradedate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TESTGRADETABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [student] ASC,
    [teacher] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.[TESTRATINGTABLE]
           ([student]
           ,[teacher]
           ,[grade]
           ,[gradedate])
     VALUES
           (1,'ALICE','A','2016-08-05'),
           (1,'BOB','A','2015-01-25'),
           (1,'CHARLES','C','2017-05-12'),
           (1,'DAVID','B','2013-09-25'),           
           (2,'BOB','D','2014-02-01'),
           (2,'CHARLES','A','2016-04-26'),
           (2,'DAVID','C','2016-05-02')
```

Comment: Create two pivots and then join them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still prefer good ol' `MAX(CASE)` (which is created by `PIVOT` in the background), lots of Cut&Paste&Modify, but efficient.

*Look Ma, no Joins*

```
select student, 
   max(case when teacher = 'ALICE' then grade end)       AS ALICEGrade,
   max(case when teacher = 'ALICE' then gradedate end)   AS ALICEGradeDate,
   max(case when teacher = 'BOB' then grade end)         AS BOBGrade,
   max(case when teacher = 'BOB' then gradedate end)     AS BOBGradeDate,
   max(case when teacher = 'CHARLES' then grade end)     AS CHARLESGrade,
   max(case when teacher = 'CHARLES' then gradedate end) AS CHARLESGradeDate,
   max(case when teacher = 'DAVID' then grade end)       AS DAVIDGrade,
   max(case when teacher = 'DAVID' then gradedate end)   AS DAVIDGradeDate
from TESTGRADETABLE
group by student
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to create two Pivots.  The desired results can be achieved via a Dynamic Pivot.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (values (student,teacher+''Grade'',cast(grade as varchar(max)))
                            ,(student,teacher+''GradeDate'' ,cast(gradedate as varchar(max)))
                     ) B (student,item,value)
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(concat(teacher,'Grade')) 
                                                              +','+QuoteName(concat(teacher ,'GradeDate')) 
                                               From YourTable  
                                               Order By 1 
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Generated SQL Looks Like This:**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (values (student,teacher+'Grade',cast(grade as varchar(max)))
                            ,(student,teacher+'GradeDate' ,cast(gradedate as varchar(max)))
                     ) B (student,item,value)
      ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in ([ALICEGrade],[ALICEGradeDate],[BOBGrade],[BOBGradeDate],[CHARLESGrade],[CHARLESGradeDate],[DAVIDGrade],[DAVIDGradeDate]) ) p
```

**The Subquery, which "FEEDS" the PIVOT Generates the following**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

basing on your sample date

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (student int, teacher varchar(7), grade varchar(1), gradedate varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (student, teacher, grade, gradedate)
VALUES
    (1, 'ALICE', 'A', '05.08.2016'),
    (1, 'BOB', 'A', '25.01.2015'),
    (1, 'CHARLES', 'C', '12.05.2017'),
    (1, 'DAVID', 'B', '25.09.2013'),
    (2, 'BOB', 'D', '01.02.2014'),
    (2, 'CHARLES', 'A', '26.04.2016'),
    (2, 'DAVID', 'C', '02.05.2016')
;
```

Script :

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select student, teacher,col,val,Col1,val1
from  @Table1
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('grade',grade))CS(COL,VAL) 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('gradedate',gradedate))CSS(COL1,VAL1)
)

Select T.student,
    MAX(T.ALICE) AS Alicegrade,
    MAX(TT.ALICE) AS AliceDate,
    MAX(T.BOB) As BobGrade,
    MAX(TT.BOB) As BobDate,
    MAX(T.CHARLES) AS CharlesGrade,
    MAX(TT.CHARLES) As CharlesDate,
    MAX(T.DAVID) As DavidGrade,
    MAX(TT.DAVID) As DavidDate  
        from  (
Select Student,
        [ALICE],
        [BOB],
        [CHARLES],
        [DAVID] 
            from  CTE 
            PIVOT (MAX(VAL)
                     for teacher in ([ALICE],[BOB],[CHARLES],[DAVID]))PVT )T
INNER JOIN 
(Select Student,
        [ALICE],
        [BOB],
        [CHARLES],
        [DAVID]
         from  CTE 
            PIVOT (MAX(VAL1) for teacher in ([ALICE],[BOB],[CHARLES],[DAVID]))PVT)TT
                    ON T.student = TT.student
                    GROUP BY T.student
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have more than one grade record for student-teacher. I will add solution that covers that. It is based on @dnoeth solution.

```
SELECT student,
   max(case when teacher = 'ALICE' then grade end)       AS ALICEGrade,
   max(case when teacher = 'ALICE' then gradedate end)   AS ALICEGradeDate,
   max(case when teacher = 'BOB' then grade end)         AS BOBGrade,
   max(case when teacher = 'BOB' then gradedate end)     AS BOBGradeDate,
   max(case when teacher = 'CHARLES' then grade end)     AS CHARLESGrade,
   max(case when teacher = 'CHARLES' then gradedate end) AS CHARLESGradeDate,
   max(case when teacher = 'DAVID' then grade end)       AS DAVIDGrade,
   max(case when teacher = 'DAVID' then gradedate end)   AS DAVIDGradeDate

FROM (
SELECT student, 
       teacher, 
       grade, 
       gradedate, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY teacher, student ORDER BY grade asc, gradedate desc) as ord
FROM testgradetable
) grades
WHERE ord = 1
GROUP BY student
```